# phonegap and dreamweaver alternative

Tags: android, cordova, dreamweaver

Currently I'm using Dreamweaver 5.5 and Phonegap to build application for android devices.
it's easy to setup/config and build, but the Phonegap version is not up to date and kinda difficult to update.

Can you suggest alternative software that similar to Dreamweaver in this way:
have live view / WYSIWYG feature, support for Phonegap and html5 and jQuery mobile code hint, easy APK properties setting and build.

thanks.

Comment: Why don't you streamline it all in Eclipse. Use Aptana and check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54868/what-is-the-best-html-editor-for-eclipse specifically the JBoss Tools eclipse plugin

Comment: sorry @TryTryAgain, your link does not explain the phonegap part, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for doesn't exist at least on the the WYSIWYG aspect. You will have to learn how to leave the confines of Dreamweaver if you want the lastest stuff. Eclipse is about as easy as it gets. There are a ton of tutorials on Phonegap site.

I wrote a tutorial on how to build Phonegap here: http://caffeineindustries.com/2011/12/phonegapcallback-1-3-0-use-it/

I use webstorm as my main IDE for writing and testing Javascript. It is awesome for me. Code hinting, configurable to almost any JS lib/framework etc.